# Google admin SDK give atlassian token instead of jira

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are using google admin sdk [token](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens) api to find user's logged in third party application using G-suite account. If we login using G-suite in Jira google create a token for atlassian application instead of jira. Any google admin api is there where we can find third party application list (users logged in using G-suite account)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear for me what exact information you are trying to fetch, how it looks like when you try to fetch it and how it should look like.

I think you are trying to fetch specific user activity logs in a different way, consider fetching ths information from the OAuth Audit logs in the Admin console through APIs with the Admin SDK Reports API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) using the *Activities.list* method. Use the **applicationName** parameter set to **token** to get the user information and application information (clientId, scopes, action, among other pieces of information).

You may also use the API Explorer to make sure that the information returned by this API is the one you want. The clientId will identify the application the user is signing in to (or granting scopes to) and it looks like a URL. *e.g. 000111223-aaabbbcc.apps.googleusercontent.com*

Comment: We are using Reports API to get audit logs but user login in jira using their gsuite account it give's attlasian in aduit logs it should be jira.